# intuition behind Monotone convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I've been trying to develop some intuition about the Monotone Convergence Theorem, and I've come up with an argument about which I'm not sure of its correctness.

**Argument for the Monotone Convergence Theorem:**

**Step 1:** To begin, we aim to demonstrate that the integral of a non-negative function, denoted as $(\int f)$, is equal to the limit of the integrals of a sequence of simple functions $(g_n)$, where each $(g_n)$ converges to $(f)$ almost everywhere and $(g_n)$ is a sequence of increasing simple functions. My proposal is to consider the sequence of simple functions described in Theorem 4.1 of Stein's book, which exhibits convergence to $(f)$ almost everywhere. This step intuitively appears to be valid, although I have yet to provide a formal proof(It's proof is obvious using MCT, but it's not possible to use it here).

**Step 2:** Moving forward, for each element within a sequence $(\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty})$, we can construct a sequence $(\{f_{n,j}\}_{j=1}^{\infty})$ of simple functions. These simple functions will exhibit monotonic convergence to the corresponding $(f_n)$.

**Step 3:** Finally, I propose the utilization of a diagonalization argument to establish the Monotone Convergence Theorem conclusively.

Your guidance and feedback would be greatly appreciated in refining this approach to the Monotone Convergence Theorem. I look forward to discussing this further.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not understanding what you're looking after :( What do you mean by "argument for the MCT"? Do you want to prove it? Do you want intuition about the MCT?

Comment: @oscar I'm trying to prove it in a way that is more intuitive(at least for me). I want to see if the proof I gave is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want intuition about the argument that establishes the MCT, the main idea is that an increasing sequence of numbers has a limit. Naturally, the limit might be $\infty$, but there's a well defined limit. In the case of the MCT, our increasing sequence of numbers is given by $$\left\{ \int f_n \right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \quad \text{with} \ f_n \in L^+,$$
where $L^+$ denotes the sets of non-negative measurable functions $X \to [0,\infty]$. Now, it should be clear that
$$\int f_n \leq \int f, \quad \text{for all} \ n.$$
This simply follows from the monotonicity of the integral. Hence, $\lim \int f_n \leq \int f$. The only thing left is to establish the other inequality. And usually, at this point, one already has the integral defined for simple functions. So that's what we need to exploit. I'll just describe the main idea, and I'll refer to Real Analysis by Folland for details.

The key idea is to find a simple function $0 \leq \phi \leq f$ such that
$$\lim \int f_n \geq \int \phi,$$
and then you take the supremum of $\int \phi$ over all simple functions $\phi \leq f$. And since $\sup_{\phi \leq f} \int \phi = \int f$, you can establish the reverse inequality, thus concluding that $\lim_n \int f_n =\int f$.